# Getting a value by multiplying values from different tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a calculation I am trying to figure out in MS Access that I need help with.

I have two tables

Table 1:  Model (Table that has different models of homes and sq.ft. of each room.

```
| ModelName | FamilyRm | BedRm1 | BedRm2 |  
| --------- | -------- | ------ | ------ |  
| Simcoe    |  110     |    85  |    95  |  
| York      |  134     |    89  |    65  |
```

Table 2: FlooringPrice (Table of upgrade cost of the flooring)

```
| Level | Price|  
|-------|------|  
|Level1 | $1.50|  
|Level2 | $2.00|  
|Level3 | $2.50|
```

What I need to be able to do, is produce a 3rd table in a report, specific to the model, that shows the cost of each room.

```
SIMCOE  
| Room    | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |  
|---------|--------|--------|--------|   
|FamilyRm |  $165  |  $220  |  $275  |  
|BedRm1   |  $127  |  $174  |  $212  |  
| Etc.
```

This is way over my head for VBA code, etc.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is a SQL question. please add a tag for it. ..... i think that if you indent 8 spaces then the column formatting does not get trashed

Comment: Tables do not appear to have any relationship. Table Model is not normalized. A UNION query could rearrange the fields to normalized structure. The desired output can be achieved with a series of queries or through VBA code writing data to a 'temp' table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Query1: ModelUNION
SELECT ModelName, "Family" AS Room, FamilyRm As SqFt FROM Model
UNION SELECT ModelName, "Bed1", BedRm1 FROM Model
UNION SELECT ModelName, "Bed2", BedRm1 FROM Model;

Query2: RoomLevels
SELECT ModelUNION.ModelName, ModelUNION.Room, ModelUNION.SqFt, FlooringPrice.Level, FlooringPrice.Price
FROM ModelUNION, FlooringPrice;

Query3:
TRANSFORM First([Price]*[SqFt]) AS TotalPrice
SELECT RoomLevels.ModelName, RoomLevels.Room
FROM RoomLevels
GROUP BY RoomLevels.ModelName, RoomLevels.Room
PIVOT RoomLevels.Level IN ("Level1", "Level2", "Level3");

Comment: I am not seeing the relationship between the two tables.  Price table is simply the multiplier to the room sizes.  I'm looking at maybe a bunch of unbound fields that populate on load, but I can't figure our the VBA statement.

Comment: I am trying the 3 queries.  the first 2 work, but the second gives an error because it is looking for a table [RoomLevels] that does not exist.

Comment: It's the query RoomLevel - no 's' on the end. Unless you want to rename the query to RoomLevels - with an 's'.

Comment: Oh my.... sorry I missed that.   Tired eyes.   Looks to work well, thanks!

Comment: I am sorry - it was my error in typing the query name in answer because my actual query is named RoomLevels - with an s - as shown in the SQL. Edited answer.

Comment: No problem.  I'm not trying to adapt Query1 to add more fields, but I'm having trouble understanding the sequence.  Basically, I think I need to do this twice.  I have to make two groups of flooring.  1st group would be for tile, ie. kitchen, bathrooms, etc.   2nd group would be for hardwood ie, bedrooms, hallway, etc.

Comment: The sample data does not reflect type of flooring but I expect it could be accommodated as another Row Heading in the crosstab. But can't be sure without accurate data sample.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what each portion of the code represents in order to adapt and manipulate it to work with more fields that I have.  I want to add more fields to the ModelUnion query, but not entirely sure where to add the field names.

Forget this... I just realized the pattern.  Oh my... I'm getting to old for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155855/discussion-between-newbievba-and-june7).

Comment: OK, so after realizing the sequence, I've added the fields I wanted.  I have a report that uses the Query3 as it's sourced, titled TilePricing.  The report works find on it's own, but if I put it in another report as a sub-report and master/child link it, I get the folllowing  "You can't use a pass-through query or a non-fixed column crostab query as a record source for a subform or subreport.  Before you bind the subform or subreport to a crosstab query, set the query's ColumnHeadings property."

Comment: Exactly why I am glad I have never required CROSSTAB queries. This article describes how to emulate a CROSSTAB http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/crosstab.html. I might be able to do a test later.

Comment: Or try setting the Column Headings property with: "Level1", "Level2", "Level3". Query in design view and click into the table section to view query properties. See edit in my answer.

Comment: Not sure what to set the Column headings property to?  it's a blank field with no options.

Comment: Tried setting the column property as you stated, but the result is columns Level 1 through 4 being empty.

Comment: OK, I think I have it working now.... I was setting the column headings to Level 1, instead of Level1, etc.... Such a small mistake makes a huge difference... Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Last question, would there be a way to not show records with "0" Value?

Comment: Where do 0 values show? Not any in the sample data.